# Passing arguments into Sendgrid template

Tags: sendgrid

I am currently using SMTAPI php to send emails using the sendgrid platform.

I am trying to send a verification email, passing in an email and hash to verify. Is it possible to add variables to the template and use addSubstitition method to set these variables when I send the email.

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email->addTo($emailToPass);
$email->setFrom('example@example.com');
$email->setSubject('Welcome to example '.$businessName.', please verify your email');
$email->setHtml('');// 
    $res = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

In the template I have included:

```
<a href="http://example.com/verify?email=%email%&hash="%hash%">
```

However when I try the: `$email->addSubstituion("%email%", $emailToPass)`
it fails to send the email and doesnt get passed the line above. I can't seem to find any documentation on this.
Has anyone tried to do this?

Comment: I'm not specific in PHP, but first of all Sendgrid changes URLs to make them "trackable". So make sure that the URL is not changed. Secondly in Java `addSubstitution` get as a second parameter an array of strings, because each recipient of that e-mail has own substitution. In your case it is a single person. Try to make a second parameter in `addSubstitution` as an array and then put $emailToPass to this array.